# Client doesn't receive message from server (Socket programming)

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

Every game tick, a server wishes to send each connected client a message, using the `sendGameWorldSections()` method. It does this in a new thread, so that the game ticker keeps running and doesn't block the thread. When the static method `Server.sendMessageToPlayer(playerID,gameWorldSectionString);` is called, the method is meant to get the `Socket` of the `HashMap<String,Socket> playerIDToSocket` , then get its `OutputStream`, and send the message to that client. The `playerIDToSocket` map maps the `playerID` (as a string) to a `Socket`. The way it stores the playerID and Socket is: the server accepts the connection from the client, the client separately sends a message as a `JSONObject` which just states the PlayerID of the player who just connected, and then the server stores it, along with the `Socket`, into the hashmap. The client is  supposed to print each message it receives onto the console. When the server sends the message to the client (The game world section), the client never receives the message. But sometimes, when I stop the Client program, it will just print every single message it received since it connected, all in one batch. Is it blocking somewhere? I can't seem to solve the problem.

GameTicker class:

```
package GameEngine;

import GameEngine.Game.PlayerManager;
import GameEngine.Game.World;
import GameEngine.Network.Server;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;


public class GameTicker extends Thread{

    public final long GAME_TICK = 2000000000; // The smallest unit of time in the game. (0.2s)
    public int ticksPassed = 0;


    /**
     * This is the beating heart of the game engine. It controls the game state, receives inputs, and informs the outputter
     * to send stuff to clients.
     *
     * Takes inputs of the current tick and then processes them (same thread)
     *
     * After each tick end, send messages to all clients informing them of the new sections.
     *
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long gameStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        long lastTickEnd = System.nanoTime();
        while(true){
            if(System.nanoTime() - lastTickEnd >= GAME_TICK){

                //GameStateManager.performPlayerActions();
                //GameStateManager.performGameWorldActions(); //
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            sendGameWorldSections();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                lastTickEnd = System.nanoTime();
                ticksPassed++;
                System.out.println(">>GAME TICKER: Tick passed. #" + ticksPassed );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends  sections of the game to each player that is logged in.
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public void sendGameWorldSections() throws JSONException {
        System.out.println("Sending game world sections..");
        for(int i = 0; i < PlayerManager.loggedInPlayerIDs.size(); i++){

            String playerID = PlayerManager.loggedInPlayerIDs.get(i);

            int xP = PlayerManager.players.get(playerID).getX(); // Position x of player
            int yP = PlayerManager.players.get(playerID).getY(); // Position y of player
            int zP = PlayerManager.players.get(playerID).getZ();

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            JSONObject gameWorldSectionJSON = null;
            try {
                gameWorldSectionJSON = World.getGameWorldSection(zP,xP,yP);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "MS to get JSON of section.");
            try {
                gameWorldSectionJSON.put("RESULT","GAME_WORLD_SECTION");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            String gameWorldSectionString = gameWorldSectionJSON.toString();
            try {
                Server.sendMessageToPlayer(playerID,gameWorldSectionString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Server class:

```
package GameEngine.Network;

import GameEngine.Game.Player;
import GameEngine.Game.PlayerManager;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

// Server class

public class Server extends Thread{
    /**
     * We must have:
     * - Player ID -> InetAddress
     */

    /**
     * STEP 1: Client connects to the server.
     * STEP 2: Client sends its user ID. The server then adds its inetaddress to the list. This is called Logging in.
     *
     * STEP 3..n:
     * - Client makes requests to the server, which the ClientHandler handles the message then replies
     * - Server can send message to a client or multiple clients.
     */

    public static HashMap<String, Socket>  playerIDToSocket = new HashMap<>(); // THESE ARE LOGGED IN.

    public void run()
    {
        listenForConnections();
    }
    private void listenForConnections(){
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {

            server = new ServerSocket(1234);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);

            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1);

                Socket client = server.accept();


                System.out.println("New client connected"
                        + client.getInetAddress()
                        .getHostAddress());

                ClientHandler connectedClient = new ClientHandler(client);

                connectedClient.start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }
//    public void sendMessagesToPlayers() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
//        while(true){
//            Thread.sleep(1);
//            for(int i = 0; i < messagesToPlayers.size(); i++){
//                ClientMessage clientMessage = messagesToPlayers.get(i);
//                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientMessage.getSocket().getOutputStream(), true);
//                out.print(clientMessage.getMessage());
//                out.flush();
//            }
//        }
//    }

    public static void sendMessageToPlayer(String playerID, String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sending message..");
        Socket socket = playerIDToSocket.get(playerID);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.print(message);
    }



    private class ClientHandler extends Thread {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        // Constructor
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run()
        {

            try {

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while(true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        // writing the received message from
                        // client
                        System.out.printf(" Sent from client "+ clientSocket +": %s\n", line);
                        JSONObject request = new JSONObject(line);
                        switch (request.getString("COMMAND")) {
                            case "SEND_SOCKET_DATA":
                                String playerID = request.getString("PLAYER_ID");
                                playerIDToSocket.put(playerID, clientSocket);
                                PlayerManager.loggedInPlayerIDs.add(playerID);
                                break;
                        }
                        out.println("You are now logged in.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
package Network;

import Game.Entities.Doorway;
import Game.Entities.EmptyBlock;
import Game.Entities.GraphicEntity;
import Game.GameWorldSection;
import Game.Player;
import Game.Tile;
import Graphics.SpriteData;
import jdk.jshell.execution.Util;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.swing.text.Utilities;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client extends Thread{


    // driver code

    private static Socket socket;
    public static boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            // edited, to include @Arthur's comment
            // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
            try {
                new JSONArray(test);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void listen(BufferedReader in){

        // Listening for server messages
        try {
            String message = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("[SERVER]: "
                    +message);
            if(isJSONValid(message)){
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
                switch(json.getString("RESULT")) {
                    case "GAME_WORLD_SECTION":
                        // Clear the tiles
                        GameWorldSection.clearTiles();
                        Tile[][] tiles = GameWorldSection.getTiles();
                        JSONObject coordinates = json.getJSONObject("COORDINATES");
                        Iterator<String> coordinatesIterator = coordinates.keys();
                        while (coordinatesIterator.hasNext()) {
                            String coordinateKey = coordinatesIterator.next();
                            JSONObject coordinateJSON = coordinates.getJSONObject(coordinateKey);
                            int real_x = Integer.parseInt(coordinateKey.split(",")[0]);
                            int real_y = Integer.parseInt(coordinateKey.split(",")[1]);
                            int painted_x = real_x - json.getInt("LOWEST_X");
                            int painted_y = real_y - json.getInt("LOWEST_Y");
                            JSONArray entities = coordinateJSON.getJSONArray("ENTITIES");
                            for (int i = 0; i < entities.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject playerObj = entities.getJSONObject(i);
                                switch (playerObj.getString("NAME")) {
                                    case "EMPTY_BLOCK":
                                        tiles[painted_x][painted_y].addEntity(new EmptyBlock());
                                        break;
                                    case "TUTORIAL_FLOOR":
                                        tiles[painted_x][painted_y].addEntity(new GraphicEntity(SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.TUTORIAL_GROUND));
                                        break;
                                    case "DOORWAY":
                                        tiles[painted_x][painted_y].addEntity(new Doorway(SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.DOORWAY));
                                        break;
                                    case "PLAYER":
                                        SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME spriteName = null;

                                        boolean isMoving = playerObj.getBoolean("IS_MOVING");
                                        switch (playerObj.getString("DIRECTION_FACING")) {
                                            case "NORTH":
                                                if (isMoving) {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_WALKING_NORTH);
                                                } else {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_FACING_NORTH);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "WEST":
                                                if (isMoving) {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_WALKING_WEST);
                                                } else {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_FACING_WEST);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "SOUTH":
                                                if (isMoving) {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_WALKING_SOUTH);
                                                } else {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_FACING_SOUTH);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case "EAST":
                                                if (isMoving) {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_WALKING_EAST);
                                                } else {
                                                    spriteName = (SpriteData.SPRITE_NAME.CHARACTER_FACING_EAST);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        tiles[painted_x][painted_y].addEntity(new Player(spriteName));
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            else{
                //
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public void run()
    {
        // establish a connection by providing host and port
        // number


        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            // reading from server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


            JSONObject clientData = new JSONObject();
            clientData.put("COMMAND","SEND_SOCKET_DATA");
            clientData.put("PLAYER_ID","123");
            out.println(clientData.toString());
            out.flush();
            while(true) {
                listen(in);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }catch(JSONException e) {
        }
        // writing to server
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, doesn't fix it

Comment: server is not sending end of line while client is expecting one - and I don't like the idea of having a `PrintWriter` instance created for each message

Comment: @user16320675 Simply changing it to `out.println()` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the `sleep()` before `accept()`. It is literally a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

In this method: you are using **out.print (message)** , but this will not flush the data since flush happens only on *printf, format or println* in **PrintWriter** when you initialize it with "true".

You should add "out.flush();" just after out.print.

```
public static void sendMessageToPlayer(String playerID, String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sending message..");
        Socket socket = playerIDToSocket.get(playerID);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.print(message);
        out.flush();
    }
```